# Unable to use Config file

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I am creating logic App. In this i want to have some values as configurable such as Email ID.
How can we create the config file for Logic App and use the values of logic App 
in run time by replacing the variables

Comment: Can you please elaborate your question little bit more

Comment: Suppose in C# we read the values from config file at run time, In same way in logic App is there any config file exists where we can save the data in key value format and same can be used in the logic App at run time.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use some files to configure the parameters, yes, you could get parameters , like with json files.

But I recommend you to use Logic Apps native parameters,however you must declare all parameters under "parameters" section of the definition.

Then you could use `@parameters('parameterName')` expression to reference a parameter within the logic app definition.

About the detailed definition you could refer to this official [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-workflow-definition-language#workflow-definition-structure), and this is about [Parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-workflow-definition-language#parameters).

**Note:you need to notice the maximum parameters is 50.**

Hope this could help you, if you still have other questions, please let me know.

Comment: Also you could refer to this blog.https://blog.mexia.com.au/preparing-azure-logic-apps-for-cicd

Comment: @vikas sharma , any more questions? If this could help you, you could mark it as the answer.